# Jmeter- java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 10.x.x.x; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Tags: java, jmeter, rmi, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

I am trying to do a distributed testing in jmeter and failing to establish a connection to remote server.
I have configured remote-hosts in jmeter.properties and started jmeter-server.bat in the slave machine.
Port 1099 is open in slave machine.

Can someone please help me on what am I missing?

I also tried to add port client.rmi.localport but this is used to send the test results back to the master, but the initial connection itself is failing

Comment: Just making sure: The host you're trying to connect to is on the same local network than the host you're connecting from? Can you ping it?

Comment: And is whatever `10.x.x.x` really is the IP address you expected to see?

Comment: Probably the wrong IP address is embedded in the stub, as per item A.1 of the RMI FAR.

Comment: I am able to successfully ping the remote hosts, so assuming they are on the same network @Sören

Answer (score 0):

If JMeter fails to establish the connection to 10.x.x.x machine on port 1099 it might mean one of the following:

1. JMeter slave process is not running. For example you didn't [configure SSL](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#setup_ssl) or didn't set `server.rmi.ssl.disable` property to `true`
2. JMeter slave process uses different port, check out effective `server_port` property value
3. It might be the case the port 1099 is blocked in operating system [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing))
4. It might be the case JVM used [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) address and you're trying to use IPv4. Check interface listening to port 1099 using [netstat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) or equivalent and if this is the case - force JMeter to use IPv4 by adding `java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` line to *system.properties* file

More information:

- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Apache JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)

Comment: A connection timeout excludes (1) as a possibility. It is a network connectivity issue.